# Minimum-Sized Encompassing Numpy Array (cropping)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I want to find the minimum-sized 2-dimensional ndarray within an ndarray that contains all values meeting a condition.

For example:
Let's say I have the array

```
x = np.array([[1, 1, 5, 3, 11, 1],
    [1, 2, 15, 19, 21, 33],
    [1, 8, 17, 22, 21, 31],
    [3, 5, 6,  11, 23, 19]])
```

and call `f(x, x % 2 == 0)`
Then the return value of the program would be the array

```
[[2, 15, 19]
 [8, 17, 22]
 [5, 6, 11]]
```

Because it is the smallest rectangular array that includes all the even numbers (the condition).

I've found a way to find all the indices for which the condition is true by using `np.argwhere` and then slicing from the minimum to maximum indices from the original array, and I've done it using a `for loop` but I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do it using numpy or scipy.

My current method:

```
def f(arr, cond_arr):
    indices = np.argwhere(cond_arr)
    min = np.amin(indices, axis = 0) #get first row, col meeting cond
    max = np.amax(indices, axis = 0) #get last row, col meeting cond
    return arr[min[0]:max[0] + 1, min[1] : max[1] + 1]
```

Comment: In my opinion your function is already pretty efficient. Is it too slow for your needs?

Comment: It works fine with my data, I was just wondering if there was a better way, the old kolmogorov complexity question. Numpy is well optimized but I had to make 3 calls to to full array comparisons before I could apply advanced indexing. I felt like there could be a function that finds the minimum and maximum indices simultaneously in one passthrough of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is pretty efficient already - but you can do better.

Instead of checking the condition for every row/column and then finding the minimum and maximum, we can collapse the condition into each axis (using reduction with the logical OR) and find the first/last indices:

```
def f2(arr, cond_arr):
    c0 = np.where(np.logical_or.reduce(cond_arr, axis=0))[0]
    c1 = np.where(np.logical_or.reduce(cond_arr, axis=1))[0]    
    return arr[c0[0]:c0[-1] + 1, c1[0]:c1[-1] + 1]
```

How it works:

With the example data `cond_array` looks like this:

```
>>> (x%2==0).astype(int)
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])
```

This are the column conditions:

```
>>> np.logical_or.reduce(cond_arr, axis=0).astype(int)
array([0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0])
```

And this the row conditions:

```
>>> np.logical_or.reduce(cond_arr, axis=).astype(int)
array([0, 1, 1, 1])
```

Now we only need to find the first/last nonzero element for each of the two arrays.

Is it really faster?

```
%timeit f(x, x%2 == 0)   #  10000 loops, best of 3: 24.6 µs per loop
%timeit f2(x, x%2 == 0)  # 100000 loops, best of 3: 12.6 µs per loop
```

Well, a little bit... but it really shines with larger arrays:

```
x = np.random.randn(1000, 1000)
c = np.zeros((1000, 1000), dtype=bool)
c[400:600, 400:600] = True

%timeit f(x,c)   #  100 loops, best of 3: 5.28 ms per loop
%timeit f2(x,c)  # 1000 loops, best of 3: 225 µs per loop
```

Finally, this version has slightly more overhead but is generic over the number of dimensions:

```
def f3(arr, cond_arr):
    s = []
    for a in range(arr.ndim):
        c = np.where(np.logical_or.reduce(cond_arr, axis=a))[0]
        s.append(slice(c[0], c[-1] + 1))
    return arr[s]
```